# Aligning HTML Data rows with headers

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have 35+ headers in an HTML table that are not aligned with the data rows. I am pasting my html and css file for your reference.

[image]

HTML Code -

```
<div class="hmcdata" >

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 page-title">LPAR Report</div>
  </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <span class="search-filter"> On-Screen Filter: <input ng-model="searchText" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 set-left">
        <div class="previous" ng-click="goBack()">Previous:</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="lparReport" style="overflow:scroll;overflow:auto"  >
        <table class="table table-striped fixed-table " fixed-header>
            <thead>
                <tr class="header">
                    <th class="table-title-text"  style="width: 100px">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'fram_name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Frame
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'frame_name' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'frame_name' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text"  style="width: 100px">
                          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'lpar_name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Lpar
                             <span class="dropup">
                                 <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_name' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                             </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_name' && sortReverse" class="caret"> </span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text"  style="width: 100px">
                          <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'lpar_hmc_name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Lpar HMC
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_hmc_name' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_hmc_name' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text"  style="width: 100px">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'lpar_id'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Lpar Id
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_id' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_id' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text"  style="width: 100px">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'state'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">State
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'state' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'state' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'os_version'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">OSV
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'os_version' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'os_version' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'logical_serial_number'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">LSR
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'logical_serial_number' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'logical_serial_number' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'lpar_env'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Lpar env
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_env' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_env' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'curr_min_procs'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Curr Min Procs
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_min_procs' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_min_procs' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>


                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'curr_procs'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Curr Procs
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_procs' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_procs' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'curr_max_procs'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Curr Max Procs
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_max_procs' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_max_procs' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'curr_min_proc_units'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Curr Min Proc Units
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_min_proc_units' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_min_proc_units' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'curr_proc_units'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Curr Proc Units
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_proc_units' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_proc_units' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'curr_max_proc_units'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Curr Max Proc Units
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_max_proc_units' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_max_proc_units' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'curr_min_memory'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Curr Min Memory
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_min_memory' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_min_memory' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'curr_memory'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Curr Memory
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_memory' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_memory' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'curr_max_memory'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Curr Max Memory
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_max_memory' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_max_memory' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'capped_mode'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Capped Mode
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'capped_mode' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'capped_mode' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'curr_uncap_weight'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Curr Uncap Weight
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_uncap_weight' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'curr_uncap_weight' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'lpar_status_flag'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Lpar Status Flag
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_status_flag' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_status_flag' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'hmc_updt_by'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">HMC Updt By
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'hmc_updt_by' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'hmc_updt_by' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'hmc_updt_date'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">HMC Updt Date
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'hmc_updt_date' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'hmc_updt_date' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'lpar_name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Lpar Name
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_name' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_name' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'earmark_procs'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Earmark Procs
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'earmark_procs' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'earmark_procs' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'earmark_proc_units'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Earmark Proc Units
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'earmark_proc_units' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'earmark_proc_units' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'earmark_memory'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Earmark Memory
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'earmark_memory' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'earmark_memory' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'security_zone'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Security Zone
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'security_zone' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'security_zone' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'ip_addr'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">IP Addr
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'ip_addr' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'ip_addr' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'application'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Application
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'application' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'application' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'server_farm'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Server Farm
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'server_farm' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'server_farm' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'uaid'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">UAID
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'uaid' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'uaid' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'failover'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Failover
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'failover' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'failover' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'vip_name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">VIP Name
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'vip_name' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'vip_name' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'lpar_gen_earmark'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Lpar Gen Earmark
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_gen_earmark' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_gen_earmark' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'lpar_gen_decom_flag'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Lpar Gen Decom Flag
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_gen_decom_flag' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'lpar_gen_decom_flag' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'gen_updt_by'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Gen Updt By
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'gen_updt_by' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'gen_updt_by' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>

                    <th class="table-title-text"  style="width: 100px">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'gen_updt_date'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Gen Updt Date
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'gen_updt_date' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'gen_updt_date' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>
                    <th class="table-title-text"  style="width: 100px">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'notes'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">Notes
                            <span class="dropup">
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'notes' && !sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span ng-show="sortType == 'notes' && sortReverse" class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <section class="">
            <tbody>
               <tr ng-repeat="lparReport in main_data_table.message | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchText" >


                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.frame_name }}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.lpar_name }}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.lpar_hmc_name }}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.lpar_id }}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.state }}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.os_version }}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.logical_serial_number }}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.lpar_env }}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.curr_min_procs}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.curr_procs}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.curr_max_procs}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.curr_min_proc_units}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.curr_proc_units}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.curr_max_proc_units}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.curr_min_memory}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.curr_memory}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.curr_max_memory}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.capped_mode}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.curr_uncap_weight}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.lpar_status_flag}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.hmc_updt_by}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.hmc_updt_date}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.l_name}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.earmark_procs}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.earmark_proc_units}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.earmark_memory}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.security_zone}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.ip_addr}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.application}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.server_farm}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.uaid}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.failover}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.vip_name}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.vip}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.lpar_gen_earmark}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.lpar_gen_decom_flag}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.gen_updt_by}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.gen_updt_date}}</td>
                   <td class="table-row-text">{{ lparReport.notes}}</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
            </section>
        </table>
</div>
```

Here is my css -

```
.hmcdata {
    margin: 25px 10px 0 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #c1bfbf;
    padding: 0px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px rgb(24, 101, 
    139);
}

.hmcdata td {
    border-right: 1px dashed #efefef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
}
.fixed-table {
    height: 500px; 
}

.table-title-text {
   align-content: center;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 8pt;
}
.table-row-text {
   align-content: center;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 8pt;
}
table.table.table-striped {
   border:2px solid #efefef;
}
```

Comment: added it again. thanks! @RickyDam

Comment: "section" shouldn't appear inside a `table` tag. Perhaps the browser is splitting the code into two tables. What happens if you remove the `<section>` element?

Comment: can you send live link or ctrl + u then send your printed data to copy past it in my editor  and try to fix your problem ?

Comment: seems to me that section isn't only the problem because browser understand table well and will isolate section outside the table !

Comment: does not work even after removing section tag. @ChrisCamaratta

Comment: removing section tag does not affect the header alignment. Any suggestion? @divy3993

Comment: @TanuSachdeva, my bad, i take it back :). Well this should not happen as it is shown in your image. I tried putting it in jsFiddel, works like a charm. Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/jvt7pLrd/

Comment: @TanuSachdeva - I pasted your code [into a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rz89f8p/2/) but wasn't able to replicate the issue. However, as Ricky points out, your HTML code is pre-processed and of little use to the problem. Maybe you can post the generated source instead by using the Elements tab of the developer tools?

Comment: @divy3993 - Jinx. :)

Comment: @ChrisCamaratta Ha ha ha :)

Comment: @TanuSachdeva You have 38 header column and 39 data column, could you try any one header(`th`) giving `colspan="2"`? I think you need it at head column with `VIP Name`.

Comment: @TanuSachdeva I tried it here check it here https://jsfiddle.net/jvt7pLrd/2/

Comment: @divy3993 added vip column header and checked the width of headers and rows. Everything matches but still does not appear to be aligned.

Comment: @TanuSachdeva, colud you check if you have somehow given `display:block` to `thead` or '`tbody`, if not what it is currently(check via inspect element/firebug). Go through this too once http://jsfiddle.net/CrYdz/1/.

Comment: @divy3993 display: block in thead. I also noticed that the width of the Frame header and data row are same(160) in elements tab but when I hover the cursor over it, it shows 148.

Comment: @TanuSachdeva Aha, go it then. Try once giving `thead` --- `display: table-header-group;` and let me know.

Comment: @divy3993 it moves the headers to the right side.

Comment: Phew! also check if `tbody` has `display: table-row-group`, if not try giving it along with keeping `display: table-header-group` for `thead`, if still no luck. Better if you have it live and if possible to share the link. As without replica it's hard to judge in your case.

Comment: @divy3993 table-row-group in tbody aligns the headers with the data but it removes overflow and increases the page length

Comment: @TanuSachdeva Okay so that was the culprit, and what do you mean by removes overflow, does that know scroll bar anymore? Also page length increases vertically or horizontally?

Comment: @TanuSachdeva I guess if i got you right, you only need now is CSS for table parent `#lnarReport { width:100%; max-width: 500px; }`. You could change `500px` to your requirement.

Comment: @TanuSachdeva Posted an answer, see if it helps you anyway.

Comment: @divy3993 Thanks, it works! :)

Comment: @TanuSachdeva, could you provide a screen shot or link if it's live.

Comment: @TanuSachdeva Oh okay great! https://media.giphy.com/media/EDt1m8p5hqXG8/giphy.gif

Comment: @TanuSachdeva posted answer below for the same. If it helped, could you accept it?

Comment: @divy3993 done :)

Comment: I counted 39 columns in the body and 35 in the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the glitch i found in your structure is that you have different number of head columnd(38) and body columns(39).

**1) Giving `colspan`**

So for that you need to either equalize them or use `colspan` for any(or which requires it) with value = `2`.

**2) Display Property for `thead` and `tbody`**

Moving forward you need to check whether your `thead` and `tbody` has the default `display` property and not something like `display: block`

`thead` should have `display: table-header-group;`

`tbody` should have `display: table-row-group;`

If this sorts out your issue, that's probably because the header and body of `table`, wasn't able to sync with each other with thier `widths` and were behaving independetly.

Now finally you need is bind your table with some specific `max-width:500px` along with `width:100%`(makes it Responsive) and `overflow: auto;` so if it exceeds the width you have your scrollbar.

I hope this helps you out.

Thank You! 
`-divy3993`

Comment: @TanuSachdeva Thanks, Glad that it helped you :)